# Converting a pandas dataframe to a pytorch tensor

Tags: pandas, pytorch, typeerror, tensor

I am trying to convert a pandas dataframe read from a CSV file to a pytorch tensor, but am getting a type error.

I tried doing this:

```
    df = pandas.DataFrame({"spam": [1, 2, 3, 4], "eggs": [5, 6, 7, 8], "ham": [9, 10, 11, 12]})
    print(type(df))
    t = torch.from_numpy(df.values)

    dataframe = pandas.read_csv('dataset.csv')
    print(type(dataframe))
    tens = torch.from_numpy(dataframe.values)
```

This works perfectly for df, but throws a type error for dataframe

```
TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.
```

Both the types are exactly the same

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: What is the content of `dataset.csv`? You obviously have non-numeric data here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue usually arises when your DataFrame contains non-numeric or mixed types. The `.values` attribute returns a NumPy array, but PyTorch expects a specific type.

1. Check DataFrame dtypes: `print(dataframe.dtypes)`. Make sure all are numeric.
2. Convert non-numeric columns: `dataframe = dataframe.astype(float)` or selectively convert columns.

Try something like this:

```py
# For specific columns
dataframe['some_column'] = dataframe['some_column'].astype(float)

# For all columns
dataframe = dataframe.astype(float)

# Then convert to tensor
tens = torch.from_numpy(dataframe.values)
```

Make sure the conversion is meaningful for your application.

Comment: some of my columns were objects while the rest were int64. Changed that and it works now thanks!